# Emacs different python venvs in different frames

Tags: python, emacs, virtualenv

I am using emacs 24.5 on my ubuntu 14.04 desktop and am using the pyvenv package to manage my virtual environments.

I have two different python virtual environments, one uses python 2 and other uses python 3.
I have 2 projects, both on different virtual environments.
I want to simultaneously compare the 2 projects.

So i opened a second frame in emacs (C-x 5 2) and used pyvenv-activate to activate my second environment. But it changes it in both the frames.
How can i make pyvenv-activate specific to a frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is the following: Run [two emacs daemon](http://tychoish.com/post/running-multiple-emacs-daemons-on-a-single-system/)s in a single system

My suggestion would be to run another emacs instance,
Since you did `C-5 2` to create a new frame, both those frames are using the same emacs process
and thus virtualenv will not work.
By running two daemon instances you will not have this problem.
I have linked you to a useful guide for this.

Comment: Works perfectly nice, just have to use alt-tab instead of switch frames though but worth it.

Comment: Great! glad I could help